# I am using tmap library to make a plot of vector dataset. I am unable to add the latitude and longitude in degrees

Tags: tmap

I am trying to spatial plot from the attribute table of a vector file.
I am unable to add latitude and longitude in degree minutes.
Here is the code.
Now kindly help me to add the latitude and longitude to the map with regular interval.

Comment: tm_shape(Glacier_2019) + 
  tm_polygons("Aera", title = "Area(sq.km)", n=10, palette = "Spectral", labels= c("0-10","11-20","21-30","31-40","41-50","51-60","61-70","71-80","81-90","91-100","101-110","111-120","121-130","131-140")
  ) + 
  tm_scale_bar(width = 0.20, position = c("left", "bottom"),) +
  tm_compass(position = c("right", "top"),size = 2,
             type = "4star",
             show.labels = 1)+
  tm_layout( 
    #title.position = c(0.55, "top"), 
    legend.outside = T)+
  tm_graticules(lines = FALSE)

Comment: Your code is not reproducible without `Glacier_2019`.